# There are some errors with my code and i was wondering if someone could point out what to to

Tags: c#

This code is for a shootem up game I'm working on but there are some errors in the code for the bullet, I was wondering if someone could point out my mistakes.

```
1. using System.Collections;
2. using System.Collections.Generic;
3. using UnityEngine;

4. public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
5. {
6.     public float Speed = 20f;
7.     public int damage = 5;
8.     public Rigidbody2D rb;
9.      
10.     void Start()
11.     {
12.         rb.velocity = transform.right * Speed; 
13.     }
14. 
15.     void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D hitinfo)
16.     {
17.        Enemy enemy = hitInfo.GetComponet.<Enemy>;
18.          (enemy != null);
19.         {
20.             enemy.TakeDamage(damage);
21.         }
22.         Destroy(gameObject);       }

}
```

Comment: " there are some errors in the code" Any guidance as to what errors you are seeing?

Comment: How do you know there are errors?

Comment: there are 2 errors in the console

Comment: @CampbellRussell can you update the question to include those errors?

Answer (score 0):

Typo error on

```
hitInfo.GetComponet.<Enemy>; //on line 17
```

should be `GetComponent<Enemy>()`

and I think you've forgotten an if loop at line 18.